# Does stopping google cloud instance will loose the installed programs on it ?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gpu, google-compute-engine

I have recently initialized a GPU instance on Google cloud, and installed Anaconda and installed all required dependencies before I stoped that instance. Now when I started the instance, it does not have anaconda installed in it. I found it is so weird. Please let me know if you know any details on it. I also looked into details from the doc of google, I don't find any related comments that should behave like this. 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this should not happen if programs got installed properly in persistent/boot disk file system.
 If  programs are supposedly installed in TMPFS or other memory mapped file system then after the instance is rebooted the memory contents would be lost and consequently data and links to it. 
However, this is never done as VM Instance packages are installed in persistent disk.

I guess your installation failed for some reason. Check if the packages are still installed. If you are using a Redhat Linux variant you can use `‘yum list installed’` to see all installed packages or `‘yum list installed|grep -i <package-to-search-for>` to filter out a particular package.

If the package shows up, then the issue could be related to a misconfiguration or other problem somewhere. Use `dmesg` and/or `cat /var/log/messages` to view the logs and try to find any problems there which may be related to Anaconda or GPU software.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. I know this question is dated but might help a complete beginner like myself. In my case I needed to SSH onto the instance instead of just being in the project level virtual environment.

[image]

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "europe-west2-c" "myinstancename" --project "fired-brimstone-234534"
```